# What's Best way to Bind collection of Enums ( List<Enum> ) to a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, drop-down-menu, bind

If I have the following enum

```
enum RequestStatus
    {
        Open = 1,
        InProgress = 4,
        Review = 7,
        Accepted = 11,
        Rejected = 12,
        Closed = 23
    }
```

and we have the following `List`

```
List<RequestStatus> nextStatus = new List<RequestStatus>();
nextStatus.Add(RequestStatus.Review);
nextStatus.Add(RequestStatus.InProgress);
```

If we want to bind `nextStatus` to `dropDownList`we do it as belllow

```
foreach (RequestStatus req in nextStatus)
    dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(req.ToString(), ((int)req).ToString()));
```

**Is there any other best way to do this bind ?**

Comment: I think you would benefit from learning about Flags enums: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: What framework are you using? ASP.NET? WPF? Silverlight? WinForms?

Comment: @Dave White: asp.net .net 3.5

Comment: Which Presentation Framework? One answer assumes ASP.NET (not MVC) but I haven't seen you specify which.

Answer (score 3):

Binding is setting a data source and bindings, not adding items to a list, what you are looking for is (assuming this is ASP.NET Forms here):

```
dropdownlist.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(RequestStatus))
dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

That being said, I think this is pretty poor user friendliness as I certainly would not care to see "InProgress" in a dropdown. I think it would be more appropriate to store this data with a ID/Name/Key and DisplayName combo somewhere and then bind the ID and DisplayName like so:

```
var items = new[] {{ID = "Review", DisplayName = "Review"}, {ID = "InProgress", DisplayName="In Progress"}};
dropdownlist.DataSource = items;
dropdownlist.DataValueField = "ID";
dropdownlist.DataTextField = "DislayName";
dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

To clarify I am not advocating to hardcode this list and would probably load this from DB and cache, but I really can only guess at your requirements here.